FLTK: When and how does Fl_Group::add take effect?
The code below, with these two lines in this order
tab1.add(glWindow2);
window->show();

produces this image:

But if I put the add call after window->show:
window->show();
tab1.add(glWindow2);

It produces this instead:

And no amount of user provocation (switching tabs, minimizing and de-minimizing the window) will ever cause the second sphere to be seen. And yet, examining the output of this line in the debugger:
Fl_Widget * const *kids = tab1.array();

Shows that indeed tab1 has two children.
So when does add work, and how does it work, and what other operation might be needed to make it truly take effect? What this is really about, I'm resurrecting some 20-year-old code that used to work, but some 10 years ago it broke on precisely this point. I'd love to know what changed.
The program:
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Tabs.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

void glutWireSphere (GLdouble radius, GLint slices, GLint stacks);

class MyGlWindow : public Fl_Gl_Window {
private:
    float blue;
public:
    MyGlWindow(int x, int y, int w, int h, float bblue = 0.0f, 
                const char* l = 0) : Fl_Gl_Window(x, y, w, h, l) {
        blue = bblue;
    }

    void draw() override {
        if (!valid()) {
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glViewport(0, 0, w(), h());
            glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 5.0);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            valid(1);
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        // Set up the camera
        gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 4.5,  // eye position
                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  // look-at position
                  0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // up direction

        // Draw a sphere
        glColor3f(0.5, 1.0, blue);
        glutWireSphere(0.8, 20, 20);

        glFlush();
    }
};

int main() {
    Fl_Window* window = new Fl_Window(400, 800, "FLTK Sphere Example");
    Fl_Tabs mainTabs(0,5,window->w(),window->h()-32);
        Fl_Group tab1(0,20,window->w(),window->h()-32, "Tab 1");
            MyGlWindow* glWindow = new MyGlWindow(10, 60, window->w() - 20, 400 - 20, 0.0);
        tab1.end();
            MyGlWindow* glWindow2 = new MyGlWindow(10, 450, window->w() - 20, 400 - 20, 1.0);
        Fl_Group tab2(0,64,window->w(),window->h()-32, "Tab2");
            MyGlWindow* glWindow3 = new MyGlWindow(10, 100, window->w() - 20, 400 - 20, 0.5);
        tab2.end();
    mainTabs.end();
    window->resizable(window);
    window->end();
    tab1.add(glWindow2);
    window->show();
    Fl_Widget * const *kids = tab1.array();
    return Fl::run();
}


Isn't this how it's supposed to work? First, the library is told what the GUI will look like with add(..) calls, and finally show() is called to construct and show the actual window.

The code and behavior seem to match the documentation (read up to, and including,  "Creating Widget hierarchies"). Functions like add define the GUI, but only a call to show constructs the actual window. Changing the definition after the window is already constructed and displayed doesn't change the displayed window - it would first have to be constructed again from the then current definition.

So no way to dynamically add more widgets later?

I suspect it's at least possible to close the window, change its definition, and to show it again. I don't know if it is possible to do this dynamically (i.e. while the window is open), I would have to check the documentation (maybe I have time for this at some point, but not now).

Joymaker, you can add widgets after showing the window but there are some aspects you need to take care of, for instance how resizing is supposed to work. You may want to call init_sizes() after you add a new widget, remove one, or rearrange widget positions.

Q: "when does add work"?
A: Basically /always/. A->add(B) adds widget B to the list of children of widget A. If B is already a child of a group (including A) it is first removed from that group and then added to group A.
Q: "how does it work"?
A: Partially already answered above. FLTK has a "current group" Fl_Group::current() that is set whenever the constructor of an Fl_Group widget is called - by an implicit begin() in the group's constructor. All new widgets become children of the current group unless the current group is NULL. Calling end() makes the parent widget of the current group become the new current group which may be NULL, e.g. for the main window.
The problem of the example program is only indirectly related to these questions. As it stands glWindow2 becomes a direct child of mainTabs because tab1.end() is called before it is constructed. Children of Fl_Tabs are treated in a special way: only one direct child is visible at any time. Therefore glWindow2 is hidden at the start of the program - at least in FLTK 1.4 (development).
There are two (or even more) solutions to the issue:

Move MyGlWindow* glWindow2 = new MyGlWindow(...) one line up before tab1.end().
2a. Add glWindow2->set_visible(); after tab1.add(glWindow2); or
2b. add glWindow2->show() after window->show();.


I'd love to know what changed.

This is hard to tell exactly. Note that dealing with subwindows is in parts platform dependent (according to your screenshots you are on macOS). FLTK development proceeds and it is possible that your old program used a kind of "undefined" behavior. Before anybody can tell "what changed" we'd need to know what FLTK versions were concerned. "some 20-year-old code" and "some 10 years ago" is not very precise. ;-)
I suggest to concentrate on FLTK 1.4 now since this is the current development. If you have further questions I recommend to ask in the official FLTK "forum" (Google Group) fltk.general.
HTH

I forgot to mention: if you use solution 1. above, then you don't need tab1.add(glWindow2); later, you can remove this statement.
